# Overlay a part of an (not a square) image with css

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I'm trying to add an overlay to an image to represent the "progress" a user has done to complete a task - so the overlay's height should increase with time (percentege done).
Just creating a simple overlay is easy enough, I just wrapp the image and add another div below to contain the overlay with an absolute position of the wrapper div.

Something like this
HTML:

```
<div class="list">    
    <div class="badge-wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.clipartlord.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/police-badge2.png" alt="badge" />
        <div class="badge-progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list .badge-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.list .badge-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.list .badge-wrapper .badge-progress {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background: rgba(50, 250, 50, 0.5);
}
```

My problem is that my image is not a square, and I what I want is only the picture to be overlayd, not the background of the wrapper, but the image it self.

Am I making sense? :)
I've got a fiddle prepared for anyone who likes to educate me. The fiddle demonstrates the behavoir I don't want. The overlay should be contained to the image only. Is this possible?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anup1986/awd477k5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
img {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(40px, 100px, 100px, 0px); // change the first argument.
  }
#progress {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
  }
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>


</div>
```

Link below might help but might not support all browser.

[CSS Masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

**Edit:**
Basically you can create 2 images and use the css clip.

Comment: The link is for creating manipulating images with creating an svg. Not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: That is exactly the effect I'm looking for! But I don't want to base64-encode the images in the markup. Can this be solved in the provided jsFiddle in my original question?

Comment: Okey, I think I see what you did now.. I have alot of images, and I wouldn't like to double the amount to achieve the effect.
Isn't there a pure css solution, with some element used for overlaying? :)